# Show Module in a specific category Prestashop

Tags: module, prestashop, categories

I'm trying to show a module in just one category.
I've created the module, assigned to Position6
Then I've inserted this:
`{if $category->id == 10} {$displayPosition6} {/if}`
in category.tpl but nothing happens.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try removing "if clause" and see if it works. Make sure that your tpl file is at correct location:

> - /views/templates/front/: front office features.
> - /views/templates/admin/: back office features.
> - /views/templates/hook/: features hooked to a PrestaShop (so can be displayed either on the front office or the back office)